# Prove that the set $\{(x,y): y/x = 1\}$ is closed as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology

Prove that the set $\{(x,y): y/x = 1\}$ is closed as a subset of $\mathbb{R^2}$.

Would prefer if I had step by step help.

Comment: I believe this is not a closed subset.

Comment: It's not closed, because it's the line $y=x$ excluding $0$.

Comment: It is a closed subset   i tried do similar problems so i did y/x - 1 < 0 and from there idk wat to do since x cant be 0  meaning f^-1 is from (-infinity, 0 )

Comment: The set call it $S$, is not closed, since $0$ is a limit point of $S$ and yet $(0,0)\notin S$

Answer (score 3):

The best you can say is that if $f: \Bbb R^2 \setminus \{\bf 0\}\to \Bbb R$ is given by $f(x,y) = y/x$, then your set is $f^{-1}(\{1\})$, the pre-image of a closed set by a continuous function, hence closed in $\Bbb R^2 \setminus\{\bf 0\}$. This does not mean that the set is closed in $\Bbb R^2$, as pointed in the comments that $\bf 0$ is a limit point of the set not belonging to it.

Comment: can i try it like f(x) = x  and prove that the complement is open  since the inverse is still y = x  we can just assume f^-1 = (-infinity, 0 ) U (0, infinity)?  and these are an open interval so we can assume that the complement is open therefore the original set is closed

Comment: No. The result is false. The set is not closed in $\Bbb R^2$. It is only closed in $\Bbb R^2 \setminus \{\bf 0\}$.

Comment: hmm i don't understand.... i mean the subset is closed not set

Comment: I'll try again: the set $\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 \mid y/x = 1\}$ is **not** closed in $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: then why is the question from the textbook asking to prove it is closed as a subset of R^2 O.o xD

Comment: People get stuff wrong all the time. It happens.

Comment: hmmm i search a question similar to this and it similar but different the set {(x,y) : y \ne x\} and someone prove that y = x is continuous and it is closed and the complement is open